# Fontawesome with Foundation 6 - Error

Tags: zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I'd like to incorporate fontawesome icons on my Foundation Sass project and I am having an issue. I have done everything as suggested by fontawesome team and yet it is not working...

1. I bower installed the fontawesome
2. I have added the scss file to the config.yml
3. I have changed the path name to fonts folder

https://postimg.org/gallery/1h018wsm8/

What I get in my browser is weird symbols and for some reason it is not working. Can you please tell me what I am missing? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `@import` the scss file from the `bower_components` folder in your Foundation `_settings.scss` or `app.scss` file.

The reference you have in `config.yml` is the PATH to the plugin/module not the import of the actual scss file. What this does is copy the *.scss files to the `dist` directory, but they still require referencing from your site/app code.

e.g. I use `app.scss` to import the various scss files and so my @import command for Font Awesome is:

`@import '../../../bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';`

Note: this is to the specific file `font-awesome.scss` (where you set the font files path), not the whole directory so you also need to make sure you import the font files too which can be done via `gulpfile.babel.js` + `config.yml`.